# PHP pase error - imagecreatetruecolor

Tags: php, image, gd

`$img = @imagecreatetruecolor(32, 32) or return false;`

Why doesn't this work?

I get a parse error, but the code looks ok?

The same with this:

`imagefill($img, 0, 0, $transparent) or return false;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use return like this.  You must use an if statement instead:

```
if (!$img = @imagecreatetruecolor(32, 32)) {
   return false;
}
```

Comment: Deleting mine and +1ing yours but hoping that you remove that hideous `@` :)

Comment: @Ann you will see errors that you can then fix. Do not use `@` to suppress errors. When on a live site, use `error_reporting(0)` in order to not show them to the public

Comment: Furthermore, `@` in PHP is very, very slow.

Comment: @Peeka agreed the @ should be removed.  I was just keeping it consistent with the asker's code.